# How do I allow other physical machines on my LAN to connect to a web server hosted within my local virtual box windows VM?

Tags: networking, windows, virtualbox

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 within Virtual Box v4 with os x 10.6 as my host.

Within Windows Server, I am running [IIS](https://www.iis.net/) and I have successfully been able to access my web server with Internet Explorer 8 --> http://localhost because I get the [basic IIS home page.](https://superuser.com/questions/205837/browser-is-redirecting-to-the-iis7-page-when-i-try-to-go-to-www-pandora-com-i-d) . So I know IIS 7.5 is running.

Under virtual box's network settings, I change from NAT to Bridged so that I can access the IIS server outside the VM in my Macintosh OS X environment in Safari.  From within the Windows Server environment, I open up "cmd.exe" and enter "ipconfig", which gives me the IP address assigned by the router (starting with 192.168.X.X).

I open Safari 5 from OS X, and navigate to 192.168.X.X IP address, and again I successfully see the [basic IIS home page](https://superuser.com/questions/205837/browser-is-redirecting-to-the-iis7-page-when-i-try-to-go-to-www-pandora-com-i-d).  This is great, but now if I move to a different desk with a different physical machine and try to access 192.168.X.X it has no clue what I'm talking about.

So I'm wondering what I need to do? Do I need to account for default gateway? Is there another setting that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Post 80 is typically closed by default on OSX. When you used Safari on your Mac and hit the IIS web browser, OSX was using the loop back interface.

Try to connect to port 80 on another box using something like the following:

```
nc -z -w1 192.168.x.x 80
```

This will let you know if the port is open. If it is closed you will need to open it to allow requests to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the IP addresses 192.168.x.x are private. They cannot be accessed by computers/hosts in other networks. If the IP addresses are assigned by a WiFi access point, both machines must be connected to the same access point to see one to the other.

If you want to access the virtual machine from a computer located in other network, you must consider to configure the router (e.g. the supplied by your internet provider) to assign a public IP address to that VM or to act as a reverse proxy.